# WooCommerce Stripe Payment - Cloning PaymentMethod Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments, hook-woocommerce

I am using [WooCommerce Stripe Payment](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-stripe/) Plugin and cannot get any answers from the support so hoping to try on here.

I am basically modifying a few setting to make a Stripe Direct Charge on a connected account.

Here are my changes:

1. added the connected account id in the header

```
add_filter('woocommerce_stripe_request_headers', 'vnmBug_addToStripeHeaders', 20, 1);
function vnmBug_addToStripeHeaders($headersArray) {
    $stripeUserID = 'acct_';
    $headersArray['Stripe-Account'] = $stripeUserID;
    return $headersArray;
}
```

2. Modified the stripe.js file to include the connected account id

```
var stripe = Stripe( wc_stripe_params.key, {
    stripeAccount: 'acct_',
} );
```

3. Added the application_fee in the stripe request body

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_stripe_request_body', 'add_application_fee', 20, 3 );
function add_application_fee( $request, $api ) {

    //Try to retrieve the order ID from the metadata
    $order = null;
    if (isset($request['metadata']['order_id'])){
        
        $orderID = $request['metadata']['order_id'];
        $order = wc_get_order($orderID);
    }
    
    //This filter is hit multiple times, so the order ID might not be available. If not, just return the request.
    
    if (!$order) {
        return $request;
    }
    
    $applicationFee = 99;   //  <- Use this for testing
    
    if ($applicationFee > 0) {
        $request['application_fee_amount'] = $applicationFee;
    }
    
    return $request;
}
```

Then when I put through a test order I receive the following error response.

> No such PaymentMethod: 'pm_'; OAuth key or Stripe-Account header was used but API request was provided with a platform-owned payment method ID. Please ensure that the provided payment method matches the specified account.

I read that I need to clone the payment method https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/connect#cloning-payment-methods but not sure how to add this part in the code? Also i am not 100% sure if this is the solution either?

Any help would be appreciated.

I tried modifying a few different hooks in the Stripe API but with no luck.

Comment: At what point do you create the payment method? Stripe-Account header needs to be passed there as well.

Comment: The official Stripe Woocommerce plugin manages the payment method and we can use the filters provided to add functionality. So they provide 'woocommerce_stripe_request_headers' for this. They do not offer a filter for PaymentMethod. So I have to find another solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If feel like you removed a lot of your code - maybe for the sake of clarity - but some of it is more confusing now.

For instance, your error:

> No such PaymentMethod: 'pm_'; OAuth key...

Is the error actually giving 'pm_' ? or did you remove the ID for length ?
If not that error means you literally passed 'pm_' as a string.

I'll explain how payment method cloning works, and maybe that will help:

1 - Get a Customer and attached Payment Method objects on your Platform.
How you get there isn't very important, there are multiple ways to do it.
We'll call the objects `cus_platform` and `pm_platform`.

2 - [Clone the Payment Method onto your connected account](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/connect#cloning-payment-methods).
This call is pretty confusing, because it's a `PaymentMethod.create()` call where you're setting the connected account ID as `stripe-account` header, but use `cus_platform` and `pm_platform` as values.
In any other situation, a call authenticated as a connected account containing platform objects would not work.

What this call does is create a copy of the Payment Method on the connected account - this has a different ID, and doesn't have a related Customer yet.
We'll call it `pm_clone`.

3 - Optionally, [attach](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/attach) this `pm_clone` to a Customer on the connected account (`cus_clone`).

This is optional, but without it you'll only be able to process one payment with `pm_clone`.

At the end of this set up, you would have 2 pairs of objects:
-`cus_platform` and `pm_platform`, used to process payments on your Platform.
-`cus_clone` and `pm_clone`, used to process payments on behalf of the connected account they exist on (with the `stripe-account` header)

Comment: Yes I removed the 'pm_' and 'acct_' details as these are long and I did not want them visible. Sorry I should have mentioned it. Thanks for the detailed insight. I will review it over and see if it helps me and come back to you later. If it helps the official Stripe woocommerce plugin handles the PaymentMethod and does not offer a built in filter to modify this so im trying to find a solution around this.

Comment: Do you actually need to clone Payment Methods ?
Because you could just handle Payments on your connected account without storing any object on the platform.

Comment: I am not sure as i was just following the guide for direct charges. I will have to look into this option. Do you have any examples of this approach? thanks

Comment: If you use Direct charges and have payment methods collected on your platform, then you need to clone payment methods. If not, you can just process everything on the connected account using the `stripe-account` header. Once you know this, any payment flow can be implemented that way. (https://stripe.com/docs/payments/more-payment-scenarios)

Comment: ok thanks, i checked and i am trying to process everything on the connected account using the stripe-account header.  But this is where I am receiving the error i mentioned above. But I have a feeling that the woocommerce filters are not working correctly e.g. 'woocommerce_stripe_request_headers' when i add in the code in the steps in this guide https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges

Comment: so that means i do not need to clone the paymentMethod, so something is missing or incorrect in my approach?

Comment: The error you got suggested you used a pm_token which exists on the platform, but used the `stripe-account` header of a connected account. This would indicate the you should either clone this payment_method on the connected account, or have saved the payment_method on the connected account in the first place.

Comment: ok i will have to dig deeper into the plugin code to see if there is a conflict as it seems the code calls a GET request to fetch the API endpoint first before processing the payment intent, but as im adding the connect account id in the header causes it to fail (error 'No such PaymentMethod') . If i remove the header '$headersArray['Stripe-Account'] = $stripeUserID'  it does not fail but obviously is no longer a Direct Charge.

Comment: You might save some time by looking at the logs on your Stripe account. You can filter them with '...more' > Account and you'll see request made from your platform (=This account), or from your platform with a `stripe-account` header (=Outgoing connect requests)

Comment: ok thanks, i checked and its the plugin which has the issue of not being able to edit the connect account id in the header. It works for Destination Charges but not Direct Charges. I am unable to edit the official plugin code so as of today there is no way to make this work with the Woocommerce Stripe Payment Gateway plugin. However, when i tested this in a local environment using the Stripe API from a test PHP script following your original post answer setup worked perfectly.